# Style-able collapsible <fieldset> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, fieldset, toggleclass

There is a log-in and registration form in separate fieldset-s like shown below:

```
<fieldset class="login selected">
    <legend class="login_link">Login</legend>
    <div class="form_container">
        <form id="loginform">
            [loginform]
        </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="reg">
    <legend class="registration_link">Registration</legend>
    <div class="form_container clearfix">
        <form id="regform">
            [regform]
       </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

one is open another is closed by default with css styling

```
.login .form_container {
    display: block;
}
.reg .form_container {
    display: none;
}
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
.selected {
    border: 1px inset #000;
}
legend {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

fieldset-s can be collapsible using jQuery. Adding and removing the .selected class allow to nicely style the open and the closed separately

```
$(".login_link,.registration_link").live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().children().children('.form_container').toggle();
    $(this).parent().parent().children().toggleClass("selected");
});

​
```

see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/43UUP/11/embedded/result/

Can you make more optimal code to do this?

Comment: Instead of $(this).parent().parent().children() look up .closest() e.g. $(this).closest('form') and live() is depreciated

Comment: Oh wait - you have two forms, both inside fieldsets.. that's not good semantically

Comment: @popnoodles That's a markup error per HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
$(".login_link,.registration_link").on("click",function(){
    $(".form_container").toggle()
                        .closest("fieldset")
                        .toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Note: As of jQuery 1.7, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwrZP/).

Comment: it has forms inside fieldsets

Comment: I learned SO doesn't like just a link being posted by trying to post one and it told me. Recently. Perhaps you've had the time to forget that. The js you posted is exactly what I posted in the first instance which doesn't work for the HTML given. The answer, without the corrected HTML, or without the JS that works for the HTML shown in the OP's post is unhelpful. Are you saying that's not true?

Comment: You're saying your answer, posted here is correct? It's not. $(this).closest('form').find('fieldset') - there is no fieldset in the closest form.

Comment: Yes but I did explain that. `The jquery you've posted doesn't work for that HTML the OP posted and the jsfiddle you've linked to is different javascript. ` Now you've removed your comment saying I didn't tell you that.

Comment: @popnoodles, deleted my comments. The comment thread is too long and adds noise to the page. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

I've build a script for that purpose for a project once.

I'm binding the `click`-event to each legend in a fieldset with a class `view_toggle`.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="view_toggle">
    <legend>Some fieldset title to click on</legend>

    <div class="view_toggle_contents">Fieldset contents to appear after click</div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
/* view toggle for fieldsets */
.view_toggle legend {
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    cursor: pointer; }
.view_toggle legend:after {
    content: ' ▼'; }
.view_toggle legend.is_active_handler:after {
    content: ' ▲'; }
</style>
```

jQuery toggle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('fieldset.view_toggle').each(function() {
        var handler = $(this).find('legend');
        var toggledObject = $(this).find('.view_toggle_contents');
        toggledObject.hide();
        handler.click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('is_active_handler');
            toggledObject.slideToggle(300);
            toggledObject.find(':input:not(:button):visible:enabled:first').focus();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where does `UL` come from?... none in OP markup, or in your demo markup either

Comment: @charlietfl Copy&Paste mistake. I replaced it with a class (`view_toggle_contents`) for this example (also added that class to the HTML part). You might as well just insert a `div`.

Comment: not bad, but i think find() is slower than parent() and children(). this is why i'm not using it if there is another solutions

Comment: @eaposztrof I didn't thought about that yet. Nice hint, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fieldsets belong inside forms anyway

```
<form>
<fieldset class="selected">
    <legend>Bejelentkezés</legend>
    <div class="form_container">        
            [loginform]
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Regisztráció</legend>
    <div class="form_container clearfix">
            [regform]  
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>​
```

Slight change to your CSS

```
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
.selected {
    border: 1px inset #000;
}
.form_container {
    display: none;
}    
.selected .form_container
{
    display:block;                
}
legend {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
​
    ​
```

Less jQuery

```
$('legend').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('fieldset').toggleClass('selected');
});​
```

Though in reality clicking either toggles both

Comment: nice, but i think find() is slower than parent() and children(). this is why i'm not using it if there is another solutions.

in this case i have two different forms.. so the closest('form') not the solution.

Comment: and that's worth a downvote? you need to fix your form/fieldset semantics.

Comment: dunno who was that and why.. i know the right form positioning, but in this case it was irrelevant.